# Magento multistore doesn't work when store view created

Tags: magento

I am trying to do a multistore set up. I already have 2 working websites in this set up which I myself have configured. Now when I am trying to do the same for a 3rd website it is not working.

Also I have tried deleting everything related to this 3rd website and redid it. Until I added the store view it was showing the correct URL with 404 (magento page) page error.

But once the store view is added, the website redirects to the original store.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Check in admin:
System->COnfiguration->General->Web->Url options->Add Store Code to Urls

Comment: Thanks man, when I was doing this, I saw I didn't mention the unsecure base url instead I just specified the secure base url.  That was the reason :[